# Inject GeoServer user into SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, geoserver

I'm setting up a GeoServer installation to communicate with an Oracle database.
I need a way to inject the GeoServer username into the SQL query so that authorization of data can be performed.   I've tried using the `${GSUSER,geoserver}` parameter in the SQL view but it is taken as literal.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This new functionality was developed to address accessing data with a specific user: 
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/sqlsession.html

However it makes GeoServer send down the user that was authenticated in GeoServer into the sql, and it's not something you can use inside a SQL view, it's restricted to the session scripts.

For a sql view you'll have to pass down the user as a parameter from the OGC request, &viewparams=myuser:test and then have ${myuser} in the SQL view (the default value is specified in the parameter table)